# Localhost cookie in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to write cookie in ASP.NET using C# with this simple code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserToken");
cookie.Value = userToken.access_token; //string
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

[image: Cookie]

Cookie was build. I am using Chrome browser but the value (Konten) always empty. What's the problem?

I also try to read this cookie with this code:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserToken"] != null)
    string userToken = Request.Cookies["UserToken"].Value;
```

"UserToken" cookie is not null but the value was empty string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just check the `userToken.access_token` value before storing it in the cookie.

Comment: what kind of check? I debugged before and it's still string. Is there are maximum character to store in the cookie?

Comment: try putting any dummy string instead of access_token